# Selective indexing in R based on index values in other dataframe

Tags: r, indexing

I have a vector and a dataframe:

```
vec <- rnorm(100) 
df <- data.frame(factor = c(3, 5, 8), start = c(1, 30, 60), end = c(29, 59, 100)
```

So the dataframe looks like this:

```
 factor start  end
1      3     1   29
2      5    30   59
3      8    60  100
```

I want to apply the factor as a power of 10 to the bins with indexing going from start:end. So vec[0:29] will be multiplied by 10^3, vec[20:59] 10^5 and vec[60:100] 10^8.

My real dataset is much larger with more factors, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach :

```
do.call(rbind, 
        Map(function(x, y, z) data.frame(factor = x, vec = vec[y:z]), 
            df$factor, df$start, df$end)) -> result

head(result)
#  factor         vec
#1      3 -0.56047565
#2      3 -0.23017749
#3      3  1.55870831
#4      3  0.07050839
#5      3  0.12928774
#6      3  1.71506499
```

---

**EDIT**

Maybe you are looking for this -

```
result <- vec * 10^rep(df$factor, df$end - df$start + 1)
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
vec <- rnorm(100) 
df <- data.frame(factor = c(3, 5, 8), start = c(1, 30, 60), end = c(29, 59, 100))
```

Comment: I should have explained better in the question, but I want to apply the factor with a multiplication to the values of df, not a new column which has the factor. But I changed it to vec = vec[y:z] * x so that works, thanks

Comment: @B.Quaink My updated answer with `rep` should be more efficient I think.